Как к типу LPCWSTR прибавить LPCWSTR c++
пишу систему регистрации учитывая CreateDirectory, хочу делать папку с именем юсера в другой папке однако LPCWSTR не очень хочет дать мне к пути прибавить введенное пользователем имя
cout << "Введи имя аккаунту: ";
string choise_name;
cin >> choise_name;
#define createD CreateDirectory

ifstream checkAcc("users/team/" + choise_name);
if (checkAcc.is_open()) {
     MessageBox(NULL, L"Данный аккаунт уже зарегистрирован в нашей системе", info, MB_OK | icon_info);
}
else {
     std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
     std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(choise_name);
     LPCWSTR name = wide.c_str();
     wchar_t buff[1000];
     swprintf(buff, 1000, L"users/team" name);
     LPCWSTR konName = L"users/team" + name;
     createD(L"users/team/" + name, NULL);

}


+ std::wstring(name)

при таком варианте ошибка
E0413 не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>>" в "LPCWSTR"

Потом для результата вызвать .c_str см. также
